# Broken HTML slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been working with a simple slideshow, but either I can't get the transition effects, or the images go missing on the first run when the effects work.

HTML:

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    $('.slideshow img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){$('.slideshow img:first-child').fadeOut().next().fadeIn().end().appendTo('.slideshow');}, 3000);
  }); 
</script> 

<div class="slideshow">
  <a href="./page_1"><img src="img_1" width="700px" height="300px"></a>
  <a href="./page_2"><img src="img_2" width="700px" height="300px"></a>
  <a href="./page_3"><img src="img_3" width="700px" height="300px"></a>
  <a href="./page_4"><img src="img_4" width="700px" height="300px"></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slideshow { position:relative; width:500px; height:332px; }
.slideshow img { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; }
```

I'm pretty new to coding, so I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should select $('.slideshow **a**') as a slide instead of $('.slideshow **img**'). That's why the code run failed after calling **next()** function.

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/rofed/1/edit

Comment: Works. The transition effects don't function properly due to an error on the site itself, but the code is good in the JSBin.

Answer (score 0):

```
//defines array of img elements
var current = $('img').length - 1;
//hide all then show the initial element
$('img').hide();
$('img').eq(current).show();
//set the interval
setInterval(function(){ $('img').eq(current).fadeOut("slow"); $('img').eq(current-1).fadeIn("slow"); if (current > 0) { current += -1; } else { current = $('img').length - 1; } }, 2000);
```

Try this variation of your js function (also, do make sure that you are including jquery as well)